# How to repair R car package failure to load?

Tags: r, openxlsx

After attempting to install R openxlsx package, car package now fails to load. How do I repair R car package load error (R version 3.5.2.)?

I have checked imports/dependencies for the car package - openxlsx present.

So how the message below can be fixed?

> library(car)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘openxlsx’

Comment: have you tried `install.packages("openxlsx")` ? Dependencies have to be mentioned explicitly when you create a package, and it happens all the time that authors forget some.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Though I am mystified as to why, since I already installed openxlsx yesterday via a command and then via gui again and it kept failing.

Comment: You have to watch the output carefully, it's sometimes verbose and you might be under the impression that it worked smoothly when in fact it failed, then in between you might have installed something else or restarted R etc... dependency hell is not fun :).

Comment: For some reason I'm unable to mark this answer as accepted - the checkbox referred to in stack overflow help file is not displayed.

Comment: Because it was a comment, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `install.packages("openxlsx")`.

Dependencies have to be mentioned explicitly when you create a package, and it happens all the time that authors forget some.